# Setup Docker Container with SSH server?

Tags: docker, ssh, containers, alpine-linux, sshd

I want to setup a very minimalistic alpine linux docker container with the following capabilities:

- It runs an ssh server
- It copies over a SSH public key of my choice to which I can then authenticate

I looked into various options, and in the end decided to write my own small Dockerfile.
However, I ran into some problems.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add openssh-server

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh

ADD authorized_keys /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

**authorized_keys**

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBP8cIHIPgV9QoAaSsYNGHktiP/QnWfKPOeyzjujUXgQMQLBw3jJ1EBe04Lk3FXTMxwrKk3Dxq0VhJ+Od6UwzPDg=
```

Starting the container gives an error: `sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting`.
How can I fix my Dockerfile, to ensure the ssh server is running correctly and the authorized_keys file is there. What am I missing?

Comment: You might try to start sshd with debug flags: ```/usr/sbin/sshd -D -ddd``` to see if that can give any usefull info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to start, the SSH daemon does need host keys.
Those does not represents the keys that you are going to use to connect to your container, *just*  the keys that define this specific host.

> A *host key* is a cryptographic key used for authenticating computers in the [SSH protocol](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol/).

*<sup>Source: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/host-key</sup>*

So you **have to generate some keys for your host**, you can then safely ignore those if you do not really intend to use them.

Generating those keys can be done via

```sh
ssh-keygen -A
```

So in your image, just adding a

```sh
RUN ssh-keygen -A
```

should do.

---

For the record, here is my own `sshd` Alpine image:

```sh
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \ 
        openssh \
    && ssh-keygen -A \
    && mkdir /root/.ssh \
    && chmod 0700 /root/.ssh \
    && echo "root:$(openssl rand 96 | openssl enc -A -base64)" | chpasswd \
    && ln -s /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-e"]
```

***Extra notes***:

- I am reusing the SSH keys generated by `ssh-keygen -A`, exposing them in a volume, this is the reason why I am doing the command:

  ```sh
  ln -s /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```
- Because this is just an Ansible node cluster lab, I am SSH'ing this machine as the `root` user, this is why I need the, quite insecure

  ```sh
  echo "root:$(openssl rand 96 | openssl enc -A -base64)" | chpasswd
  ```

Comment: I tried this Dockerfile verbatim, and I get "Permission denied" when I ssh in as root with the password root.  I might not be clear on what you are doing with the key you've linked with ln -s.  Otherwise, are there additional settings needed to ssh into the server?

Comment: @k-den the default configuration of the SSH daemon is `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`. So, that is what prevents you to login with a user/password when you would be able to do it with a SSH key. This is actually the reason why I am using this key in _/root/.ssh/authorized_keys_. To use it, I have a volume that exposes the private key so I can, from my host or from another container, login with that SSH key.

Comment: If you do really want a user/password login, you could have a line In the `RUN` statement that would read `echo 'PermitRootLogin yes' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. **But mind that this should never ever be used in any sort of production setup**.